# geographic layers in mysql

Tags: .net, mysql, geography, mysql-connector

I am looking for an implementation of MySql and Geographic layers (features\rasters),

how does it work for you? which ORM \ dataaccess you are using? how do you write the geo-queries? as sql or in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least for the simple stuff, generally speaking, you have to convert a geometric object from text into a geometry:

```
INSERT INTO table (geometry) VALUES (GeomFromText('POLYGON((x y, x y, x y, x y, x y))'))

SELECT AsText(g.geometry) AS geometry FROM table
```

You can do a spatial indexes like `ALTER TABLE my_table ADD SPATIAL INDEX(my_field);`

You cannot really do much beyond the basics with GIS data in MySQL.. if you really want to do GIS stuff with a FOSS dataserver, you have to go [PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/) with PostgreSQL. See [this article](http://docs.opengeo.org/geospiel/2009/06/16/postgis-versus-mysql-spatial/).

Comment: how does it optimize the columns, is there any tiled-index?

Comment: I think for a tiled index you need PostGIS or MapServer (for FOSS stuff). You will not find advanced GIS functionality in MySQL